# How to change light direction in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I change the lighting direction in rviz?

So instead of the light coming from the left, I want it to come from the right :)

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48571/how-to-change-light-direction-in-rviz/) by [Tieske](https://answers.ros.org/users/3607/tieske/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tieske](https://answers.ros.org/users/3607/tieske/) on 2012-11-19**:
Hi, thank you for the interest. For me it is also possible to change the placing of all the objects, but I thought there would maybe be an easier solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also trying to find that out. I want it to come from the sky. I'm pretty sure that you would have to modify a file in the source code from RVIZ that would affect the OGRE scene rendering.

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0